# CodeIgniter system folder

Tags: codeigniter

Somehow, I'm not sure how, I ended up with the 3.0-dev version of CI in a production environment.  I want to replace it with 2.1 but am unsure how to.  Can I just upload the 2.1 system folder to overwrite the 3.0-dev folder or do I need to do more than that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Upgrading (and similarly downgrading) in CI is achieved by merely replacing the `system` folder.

Note: This is assuming you followed the best practices related to CI (i.e., you made any changes you needed as custom Controllers / Models / Libraries / Helpers etc. and did not make the changes to the core files themselves.

I would also strongly recommend you go through the CI 3.0 changelog and make sure you handle any case where you are using a feature that was added to 3.0 and was not present in 2.1.

CI 3.0 Changelog: http://codeigniter.com/nightly_user_guide/changelog.html